# How to unpack emotet with x64dbg and do dynamic analysis?

Tags: debugging, dll, unpacking

I am a beginner at malware analysis. I have been trying to analyze Emotet using X64DBG. I followed the steps below and succeeded once, but when I repeated the same steps, I failed. Can you tell me if my approach is appropriate?

1. I run Emotet with arguments given to `rundll32.exe` using X64DBG. The argument is `DllRegisterServer`.
2. I set a breakpoint at `NtResumeThread` to prevent the child process created by Emotet from executing.
3. I start a new instance of x64dbg and attach it to the child process. I set a `Load DLL` breakpoint to prevent execution from proceeding when it detaches from the parent process.
4. In the child process's x64dbg, I set a breakpoint at `VirtualAlloc` to identify where the unpacked executable is expanded.
5. I set a breakpoint at the location identified in **step 4** to stop just before execution after unpacking is complete.